# Querying a registry key value via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, registrykey

I'm trying to create a simple batch file that uses the reg query command to check for the existence of a value in a registry key, specifically

**`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`** **`ProxyEnable`** key.

If I run this command:

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /f 0x1 /d
```

It returns the following:

**`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
            ProxyEnable    REG_DWORD    0x0`**

It's as if it's not accepting my **`/f`** search field, as I would expect the command as entered to return no results since my value for that key is **`0x0`**.

I've tried using quotes around the "**`0x1`**", and other combinations, but wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get the idea that /F meant search?

Comment: @Squashman, under `Reg Query /?`, `/f Specifies the data or pattern to search for. Use double quotes if a string contains spaces. Default is "*".` That said, as you're only reading the key, can you not just set the data to a variable and check it with an `If %variable Gtr 0`comparison

Comment: This worked for me: `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"  /f 1 /t REG_DWORD |find /I "ProxyEnable"`

Comment: Your other option is to use a `FOR /F` to capture the output of the `REG QUERY`.

Comment: Yep worked for me too! Very nice, thanks Squashman!

Comment: @Squashman better: `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /f 1 /e /t REG_DWORD |find /I "ProxyEnable"`. I've added `/e` for exact search to prevent finding values where `1` is just a *digit* of a number (e. g. your query also finds `12345`).

Comment: @zett42, in my defense, the value of ProxyEnable should only ever be 0 or 1.  It is kind of a true or false setting.

Comment: @Squashman Would you like to turn this into an answer? I find this approach a little bit more readable than the `for /f` version.

Comment: @zett42, I've already added an example using your information in the many examples in the answer I provided below!

Answer (score 3):

As you only appear to be wanting to know if enabling proxy is toggled on, you can use this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "RR=HKCU"
Set "RK=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "RV=ProxyEnable"

For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RR%\%RK%" /V "%RV%" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%~B Gtr 0 Echo(%%B

Pause
```

If you wanted to for instance to toggle it on if it is off then change it to something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "RR=HKCU"
Set "RK=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "RV=ProxyEnable"

For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RR%\%RK%" /V "%RV%" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%~B Equ 0 Reg Add "%RR%\%RK%" /V "%RV%" /T REG_DWORD /D 0x1 /F>Nul
```

Although technically you could just run this to do that:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "RR=HKCU"
Set "RK=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "RV=ProxyEnable"

Reg Add "%RR%\%RK%" /V "%RV%" /T REG_DWORD /D 0x1 /F>Nul
```

**Edit**

To check it first using the method suggested by Squashman and improved by zett42, *because the following `EnableHttp1_1    REG_DWORD    0x0` would have been sent to `Find`*:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "RR=HKCU"
Set "RK=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "RV=ProxyEnable"

Reg Query "%RR%\%RK%" /F 1 /E /T REG_DWORD|Find /I "%RV%">Nul 2>&1||(
    Reg Add "%RR%\%RK%" /V "%RV%" /T REG_DWORD /D 0x1 /F>Nul)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Reg query** is for read registry data not for set  or change the registry data
to change the Registry data replace **`query`** with **`Add`**

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable  /d 0x1 /f
```